# phpmyadmin is not found when I install PHP 8.0.9 on windows

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm stuck in a problem with an update

I recently installed the xampp again and renamed the previous xampp folder to xampp_old for the installation of PHP 8

I started apache and mysql server, the are running.

the main localhost url `http://localhost` is opening and my websites are also opening with localhost.

but when I try to access phpmyadmin with url,I got this error:

[image: Click to see the image]

Is this due to reinstallation of xampp?

What should I do to fix this issue? Please help me with this.

Comment: you have a cvery log link, have you trried without all the baggage

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said

Comment: your image shows http://localhost/phpmyadnin?sql......... make the url only http://localhost/phpmyadnin

Comment: Still It is not opening. How can I resolve it?